# Best way to render a 2d array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to generate a graph view and I'm running into performance problems. I'd like to update the view, for example drag the starting node, and have that reflected in the underlying model. The updates to the model appear to force an update to the state for every single node in the graph. Do I just switch to a map with keys and store the columns and rows to wrap things for the presentation?

```
<Graph>
  {graph.map((row: any, i: number) => {
    return (
      <GraphRow key={i}>
        {row.map((node: any) => {
          return (
            <GraphNode
              className={Object.keys(node)
                .filter(key => node[key])
                .join(" ")}
              key={`${node.x} ${node.y}`}
              onClick={() => updateNode(toggleIsWall(node))}
              onDragStart={() => {
                setDraggedNode(node);
              }}
              onDragEnter={() => {
                handleDragEnter(node);
              }}
              onDragLeave={() => {
                handleDragLeave(node);
              }}
              onDragEnd={() => {
                handleDragEnd(node);
              }}
              draggable
            >
              <div>
                {node.x}, {node.y}
              </div>
            </GraphNode>
          );
        })}
      </GraphRow>
    );
  })}
</Graph>
```

Comment: Looks like you might benefit from using [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I implemented my own `shouldComponentUpdate` and that helped, but not enough. The fundamental issue with my approach was trying to represent the nodes with divs. divs in that quantity perform horribly. I instead used `<svg>` to represent each node. As I understand it, if that didn't get the performance I needed, using a canvas would be the next step. Hope this helps someone. Cheers!